# Translation using gettext impossible

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext

I can't translate anything on my site. To debug (on my local server), I put this

```
    bindtextdomain("mysite", "../locale"); //path is correct
    bind_textdomain_codeset("mysite", 'UTF-8');
    textdomain("mysite");
    @setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US');
    echo gettext("mon site");//keeps returning 'mon site'
```

Knowing, I generated correct mysite.mo (in the relative path ./locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/), where the translation 'mon site' appears as 'my site'

I can debug it by using 'putenv', is it possible not to use it ?

Someone could help ?

Comment: What about removing the `@`? Have you checked if the locale gets set correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Is the language en_US installed on your computer?

See this question : [Php web application internationalisation with Gettext();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974133/php-web-application-internationalisation-with-gettext)

You have to have the language installed on your computer in order to compile correctly the .mo  and to be able to use them